# How to add a CSS class when in the click event in angular 7 without using ng-Class or ng-Style?

Tags: typescript, angular7

How to add or remove CSS classes to HTML elements when I click on them in Angular7?
I want to achieve this without using Ng-Style and Ng-Class directives.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's something like this what you want to achieve (to add and remove a Class on click):

```
clicked(event) {
let oldClass = event.target.getAttribute('class');
if (oldClass == null) {
  oldClass = '';
  this.render.setElementAttribute(event.target, "class", oldClass + 'selected');
} else if (oldClass.includes('selected')) {
  oldClass = oldClass.replace('selected', '')
  this.render.setElementAttribute(event.target, "class", oldClass);
} else {
  this.render.setElementAttribute(event.target, "class", oldClass + ' selected');
}
```

Don't forget to  `import { Renderer } from '@angular/core';` and add `constructor(private render: Renderer) { }`

See the [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5v3aci?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

More info about [`Renderer`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer) and [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) or [`.replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Directive, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]',
})
export class MyDirective {

  @HostBinding('class')
  elementClass = 'custom-theme';

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

then just use it like

```
<div myDirective> </div>
```

---

For directly using inside component

```
import {Component, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent  {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {}

  click(event) {
    renderer.addClass(event.target, 'popup');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to call a function in the '(click)' event and add the classes via that function? (maybe using ElementRef)